# Print a big integer stored as an unsigned long long array

Tags: c, cryptography, rsa, bigint

I'm reviewing the security of an app for a University project, the app encrypts a file using RSA, specifically it uses this library: https://github.com/ilansmith/rsa (DO NOT use this, it has serious vulnerabilities).

(If you want to take a look, most of the operations between these numbers are implemented in the `rsa_num.c` file.)

This tool uses arrays of `unsigned long long` to store the big numbers needed for RSA (`n`, `e` and `d`):

```
typedef struct {
    u64 arr[17]; //u64 is defined as unsigned long long
    int top;     //points to the last occupied slot of the array
} u1024_t;
```

The problem is that I don't understand how the numbers are stored in this format.
What I need is being able to print the real numbers in some way, or at least a way to recover the numbers from the components of the arrays.

I tried just concatenating them like strings, but it doesn't seem right.

Thanks to whoever will be able to help!

Comment: Concatenate sounds right, as long as you do it in hex, with index 0 as LSB, and up to `top`, as far as I understand.

Comment: @Matthieu to do a basic hex->int conversion (using python's `int(hex_string, 16)` for instance), "index 0 as LSB" means that I can just dump all the bytes from the start of the array to the last byte of the `top` slot, or I need to dump u64 elements in reverse order? Sorry for the question, I'm kinda noob with endianness things

Comment: If to print (so MSB first), start from `top-1` down to `0`. In C you can use `printf("%02x", st.arr[i]);`.

Comment: `17` is unclear.  Why 17?  Naked magic numbers I guess.

Comment: @Matthieu thanks, I'll try and post the result
@chux-ReinstateMonica I have no idea honestly, it's defined in the library as `RSA_NUMBER_ARRAY_SZ`, I think it's because this library supports upto 1024 bits key and 17 is the least amount of `unsigned long long` to store those keys

Comment: No, you'd need 16 for that; they are unsigned after all. However, there may be some overflow when doing modular arithmetic (I'm guessing here).

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I've seen a few serious vulnerabilities in that code, so it's very far from perfect. I think it could have been more of a personal project.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [@Matthieu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61197091/print-a-big-integer-stored-as-an-unsigned-long-long-array#comment108261681_61197091)! Your comment worked.
I needed to concatenate the `unsigned long long`s in reverse order and reversing their bytes due to endianness.

Following his solution, I implemented this function, which works perfectly:

```
void print_u1024(u1024_t number) {
    int size = (number.top + 1) * sizeof(u64);
    for (int i = size-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%02x", ((unsigned char*)number.arr)[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Please note that this solution will probably only work on little-endian systems (most PCs).

Comment: The order is likely endian dependent.,  On another machine the other order may be needed.

Comment: Right, I'll edit the answer to make it clear, thanks.